# Does PHP support regions?

Tags: php, ide, editor, regions

In C# I can write #region and #endregion, is there an equivalent in PHP that works with all IDEs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't natively supported, but instead it would be IDE-specific. And this doesn't strictly mean `#region` support per se, but rather 'code folding' in whatever fashion any IDE (or extension/plugin) supports. [Here](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/code_folding_in_php_editor), and [here](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_code_folding.htm) are a couple of examples.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no #region in PHP. Its related to IDE/Editor actually. Not related to language.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="user-description">
  ...any code...
// </editor-fold>
```